# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs, web-deployment

```
const cities = require('./cities');
const { places, descriptor } = require('./seedHelpers');
const Campground = require('../models/campground');
const { length } = require('./cities');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/starwar-camp', {
    // useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useCreateIndex: true,
    // useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Database connected Successfully!");
});

const sample = array => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

const seedDB = async() => {
    await Campground.deleteMany({});
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        const random1000 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        const camp = new Campground({
            location: `${cities[random1000].city}, ${cities[random1000].state}`,
            title: `${sample(descriptor)} ${sample(places)}`
        })
        await camp.save();
    }
}

seedDB().then(() => {
    mongoose.connection.close();
})
```

This is what error I am getting

```
const sample = array => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at sample (E:\EDI\YelpCamp\seeds\index.js:19:64)
    at seedDB (E:\EDI\YelpCamp\seeds\index.js:27:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I am actually doing a project from udemy and I have written the same code as from the video and his code get executed without any error but not mine.

Comment: It seems like the *sample* function expects an Array and that means that it can either be the *descriptor* or *places* that is causing the error. You might have to give more information on those two variables.

Comment: Looks like `places` you import is `undefined`. You need to verify what you export from **seedHelpers.js**.

Answer (score 1):

Its because either one or all of the **descriptor** or **places** is returning null or undefined from line

```
const { places, descriptor } = require('./seedHelpers');
```

try to console these two values separately to see if they give anything

from your codes above it seems that the sample function

```
const sample = array => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
```

works just fine and its role is to give you random sample  from the array of samples

Comment: yeah , I consoled both of them separately, and it not showing any errors and as you said they are returning null or undefined values and its actually returning undefined values. Thank you for solving my issue.

Comment: if a post is helpful, make sure to vote up mate :)

Comment: well I tried but I need 15 more reputation for it, So as I will be able to do so I will definately vote up helpful replies.